# How to Create a Draggable and Non-Cancellable Bottom Sheet with Outsode Click Events in Android (Compose or Native)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I’m working on an Android app where I need to implement a bottom sheet that meets the following requirements:

- Draggable: The bottom sheet should be draggable by the user.
- Non-Cancellable: It should not dismiss when the user touches outside of it (even in the peeking state).
- Underlying Fragment Interaction: The base fragment that launches the bottom sheet should continue to receive click events when any CTA (Call to Action) button within the bottom sheet is clicked.
  I’m open to using either Compose or Native for this functionality. However, I’m struggling to find a solution that satisfies all these conditions.

What’s the best approach to create a draggable and non-cancellable bottom sheet while ensuring that the base fragment continues to receive click events?

Comment: what could i think of is skydove's FlexibleBottomSheet but I am not sure about non-cancellable. Have you checked it out? https://github.com/skydoves/FlexibleBottomSheet